# How to find two variables $a,b \in {\bf Z}$ that the matrix $A$ is orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

I have to find two variables $a,b \in {\bf Z}$ that the given $n \times n$ matrix A becomes orthogonal.
\begin{equation*}
A =
\begin{pmatrix}
 1&2 \\ 
 a&b 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
I know that a $n \times n$ matrix is called orthogonal if $A^TA$ $=$ $id$ which means:
\begin{equation*}
  \begin{pmatrix}
   1&a \\ 
   2&b 
  \end{pmatrix}
\cdot
  \begin{pmatrix}
   1&2 \\ 
   a&b 
  \end{pmatrix}
=
  \begin{pmatrix}
   1+a^2&2+ab \\ 
   2+ab&4+b^2 
  \end{pmatrix}
\stackrel{?}{=}
  \begin{pmatrix}
   1&0 \\ 
   0& 1
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Comment: You are already done, because this means that $A^TA\neq I_2$ for all $a,b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system of equations has no solution at all, since $1+a^2=1$ implies $a=0$ and hence $2+ab=2\neq 0$. hence $A^TA\neq I_2$ for all $a,b$. This is, given the computation in the question, much more immediate than to use that the norm of a column vector must be $1$ for an orthogonal matrix.

Comment: I see, i had the same thought with $a = 0$ but i was confused because the question was to find a,b, but it is impossible for $a,b\in Z$, as shown.

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution since the norm of the column vector of an [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) must be $1$. (Note that the second column is $(2,b)^T$.)

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Now solve the system of equation in terms of $a$ and $b$. However, if $b$ is restricted to be an integer, the equation $$4 + b^2 = 1$$ does not have a solution.

Comment: It does not seem to have a solution at all, since the top-left element forces $a^2 = 0$ and then the top-right element $2 + ab = 0$ becomes $2 + 0 = 0$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DietrichBurde sorry was confused by the "if $b$ is restricted to be an integer", it seemed to matter.

Comment: @CompuChip What I mean is that $4+b^2=1$ does not give a contradiction, say, over the complex numbers, but your argument (and mine) does.